# How to add transparency to the .dae model?

Tags: javascript, three.js

```
var mesh7;
loader.load("test_obj/dae/07.DAE", function (result) {

    mesh7 = result.scene.children[0].children[0].clone();
    mesh7.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
    mesh7.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    mesh7.opacity: 0.5; //it doesn't work

    objects.push( mesh7 );
    console.log(mesh7);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try add:

```
mesh7.material.transparent = true;
mesh7.material.opacity = 0.5;
```